# Setting module path in lighttpd config file?

Tags: configuration, lighttpd, path

What is the option in lighttpd.conf to set the default path for lighttpd to look for modules? My lighttpd would not start because it keeps looking for critical modules at the default path, and I had the server installed at another location. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is done with a .conf setting, rather it's set when you compile lighttpd. Depending on how you compiled it (say using `configure`, you might need to set `--prefix` to Specify your installation directory if you want to install Lighttpd at a location different from default /usr/local/.  Other path setting command-line switches for configure: --bindir, --sbindir, --datadir, --libdir, & --sysconfdir.

Using [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/), you'd pass an option like `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/`

[Nixcraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/installing-and-configuring-lighttpd-webserver-howto.html) has a nice install how to and there's always [lighthpd.net](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ConfigurationOptions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use lighttpd's `-m` command line argument to specify the modules directory.

Comment: Works like a charm, needed it after building lighttpd from source.